# How to pass a parameter to a laravel controller from redirect within the same controller

Tags: laravel

How do I pass a true false value to the controller from the redirect in the class and to the router and back to another function in the same controller class if that makes sense
Like

```
public function 1() {
    return redirect('route2');
}

public function2() {
    I need to access the variable here that some how gets passed from the first function
}
```

Because these functions are both on my main controller and I need to pass a variable through the route
and back into the controller or is there a way to put a state variable on the class or something I just need to call a function on the controller with conditions from the previous controller function that called called the redirect route.

Also sorry if I am mixing up class and function I am new to laravel and MVC in general.

Comment: What do you mean by "put a state variable on the class", what exactly are you trying to achieve in your functions?
I mean, you could call the function directly?

Comment: @Aless55  So basically if I got to this page from a redirect in the controller logic I need the controller logic to work differently as opposed to if I got their from the the A tag that sends me to that page regularly

Comment: @Aless55 ahhh yes I think I was severely overthinking this.. MVC got me confused... yes all I had to do was call the function directly silly me hahah

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public function first() {
    return redirect()->action(
        [YourController::class, 'second'], ['value' => true]
    );
}

public function second($value = null) {
    
    // whatever you want

}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/redirects#redirecting-controller-actions

Answer (score -1):

I think this code help you:

```php
public function 1() {
    return to_route('YOUR_ROUTE_NAME', ['value' => 'some things...']);
}

public function2(Request $request, $value) {
    // Use the value passed as a route parameter
    // $value is 'some things...' 


}
```

Comment: Please describe how this solution helps the problem, otherwise your code is nor very useful to beginners.

Comment: Well I need something like @Ali SSN is doing except I am getting the error 

Too few arguments to function controller:function2(), 1 passed in controller.php on line 54 and exactly 2 expected, so Instead I am going to do a more hacky solution for now and just set some sort of global state variable that changes when the controller functions are called.